# echo Php variable from javascript and javascript is in php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have jQuery function in a PHP function. I have `id` of a `div` in a PHP variable. I want to pass this variable to the jQuery code, but it is not working:

```
public function food(){
    echo '<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#$this->ccid #food").show();
    });
   </script>';
}
```

Comment: Osama may i ask why your roll back the edition

Comment: You may want to have a look at how to specify strings in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: what's the status of this (old) question? You've been given an answer but wasn't accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use string concatenation:

```
public function food(){
    echo '<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#' .$this->ccid. ' #food").show();
    });
   </script>';
}
```